# how to display uploaded pdf/text_files/videos using mongoid-paperclip

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I am using mongoid-paperclip  gem to upload files. I am able to display images which I have uploaded. But how to display the pdfs/videos.

Please help me to get the solution.

This is Image model.

```
Class Image
  has_mongoid_attached_file :logo
  validates_attachment :logo, :content_type => [ "application/pdf"]
  validates_attachment_content_type :logo, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"]

  field :logo
end
```

View file:

```
<% @images.each do |image| %>
<%=  image_tag(image.logo.url(:original)) %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem .. please upload log ..

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
  validates_attachment :logo, :content_type => [ "application/pdf"]
  validates_attachment_content_type :logo, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"]
```

with

```
  validates_attachment_content_type :logo, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "application/pdf"]
```

No need to validate separately as you are validating the same `logo` field.

I am assuming that you have installed `GhostScript`(`brew install gs` if using Mac). Thats a requirement for pdf upload using `Paperclip`. If not, then install it first and restart rails server.

In your view, add the following code:

```
<% @images.each do |image| %>
<% if image.logo.image_content_type == 'application/pdf' %>
   <iframe src=<%= image.logo.url(:original) %> frameborder="0"></iframe>
<% else %>
    <%=  image_tag(image.logo.url(:original)) %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

`iframe` is an inline frame mechanism used to embed another document within the current HTML.
The above code is tested using environment: Ruby 2.1.0, Rails 4.0.2, Mac OS Mavericks, Paperclip 3.5.3

**EDIT**

Checkout the [paperclip-ffmpeg](https://github.com/owahab/paperclip-ffmpeg) gem which is used for adding video handling to Paperclip via ffmpeg. Make sure that `FFMPEG` is installed on your machine.

Comment: I tried and now I am able to display pdfs. Thank you Kirti. I have one more doubt, How to display videos?. Can you help me in this?

Comment: Did you complete the configuration as said in "Requirements" section of the gem. See details at: https://github.com/owahab/paperclip-ffmpeg

Comment: Please help me how to view uploaded text files/pdfs and videos.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your model

```
has_attached_file :logo,
                :url  => "/assets/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                :path =>  ":rails_root/public/assets/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

then in view

```
    <p>
     <%= link_to 'My PDF', @variable.logo.url %>
   </p>
```